# My gRPC source file can't read grpc's service

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

This is my .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  // Sends another greeting
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I declared service and messages here. And I made cc file and header file by protoc.exe
I followed gRPC c++ Tutorial, and i wrote greeter_server.cc

[image: screenshot of GreererServiceImpl]

But geeter_server.cc file can't read service Greeter. But it can read variable of Messages
What is the problem?

I included header file well, And i searched google but i can't find answer
help me please

Comment: Please copy-and-paste code into question instead of using screenshots. Screenshot images prohibit others copying-and-pasting code to help you and may not outlive the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gRPC with C# but, if you're using `protoc`, you will need to use two plugins. The first generates the Messages defined in your proto files and the second generates the Services. I suspect, you used the first and not the second.

Comment: That said, I think (!?) the C# gRPC (and Protobuf) implementations come bunded with the protoc compiler and you do not need to call protoc directly when using e.g. Visual Studio. Please see [gRPC: C# | .NET](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/).

Comment: Did grpc.pb.h and grpc.pb.cc extension files get generated?